# Why is my fresh tofu fa (douhua) sour?

Tags: dessert, tofu

I made some fresh tofu fa following this recipe: http://ieatishootipost.sg/how-to-make-tau-huay-tofu-fa-almost-everything-you-need-to-know/

When I eat the tofu (about half an hour after pouring, so it just set), the tofu is sour, especially at the bottom.

I followed the recipe, but used gypsum instead (2 tsp).
The soybeans were soaked overnight, then shelled, and thinking it might have been my water, I used bottled spring water.

I've read that lactone can make the tofu sour, but I used food grade gypsum.

Comment: You checked your water, have you checked your beans?  If the beans are somehow a little bit sour, or become so during the processing, that might be a variable you can test.  Either get fresh beans and test the recipe again (in case of a bad batch), or make something else with the beans (similar processing preferred) and taste for sourness without gypsum.

Answer (score 2):

Quality of the beans aside, it's likely that you soaked your beans for too long and they have started to ferment. Gypsum is basically tasteless so it should not have an effect on the taste.

When soaking soybeans for soymilk you will want to soak them for no longer than six hours (four in the summer or areas with high humidity). If you soak them for too long, they will start to ferment (thus producing the sour taste), which is likely to be the cause of the sour taste. If you may also want to consider soaking them in the refrigerator to prevent fermentation.

Consider tasting the soymilk batch you produce to ensure that the beans you used has not started to ferment.